# リッチなテキストエリアを実現するライブラリやgemを教えてください

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery

Railsで開発中のプロジェクトに

まさに、このstackoverflowの入力欄の用に、[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

リッチなテキストエリアを実現したいと思っています。

これをするための、jqueryのライブラリやrailsのgemなどがあれば教えていただきたく。

何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

Javascript系で動かすのでしたらTinyMCEやckeditor辺りが情報も多いですし一般的な気がしますのでチェックしてみてはいかがでしょうか？